# Mark email as read gmail IMAP with php

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I have this code that gets what I want, but I want to go back and mark all the emails hit as read

Here is the code I am using

```
<?


$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}MY FOLDER';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';


$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


if($emails) {
    
    $output = '';
    
    rsort($emails);
    
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'read').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';
        
        
    }
    
    echo $output;
} 

imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

I tried adding this at the end of the foreach statement:

```
             imap_setflag_full($inbox,$email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);
```

But that does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

By default `imap_search` returns message sequence numbers not UIDs.

That means you shouldn't use `ST_UID` flag in `imap_setflag_full`

```
imap_setflag_full($inbox,$email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged");
```

**OR** add it also to `imap_search` (keep in mind you might have to change your `imap_fetch_overview` then).

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL', SE_UID);
```

Also keep in mind that you can reduce calls to imap_setflag_full by adding it after the foreach and giving all the id's as one sequence.

```
imap_setflag_full($inbox, implode(',', $emails), "\\Seen \\Flagged");
```